# Azure Media Service: dynamic encryption and key delivery services not working Properly

Tags: c#, azure, encryption, video-streaming, azure-media-services

I had a requirement to Stream video online and protect the stream, so i started using Azure Media Services and for stream protection i used AES-128 dynamic encryption and key delivery services, while implementing this i had mentioned expire time of token key generated using GenerateTestToken() function as 20 mins from current time,this token was used in authorization header of the stream, this worked fine for first 20 mins the steam was getting encrypted and decrypted properly,after 20 mins the steam stopped working so i generated new token key using GenerateTestToken() but this time stream failed to decrypt the stream, this decryption of stream failed for next 20 mins , after this i again try this time stream gets encrypted and decrypted properly again

so alternatively the token key generated using GenerateTestToken() works or fails to decrypt the steam , this is really confusing please help

Comment: Suraj,
In general, for one playback session, the content key is only retrieved once from keydelivery service. We need clarification if this is for one playback session or different playback sessions? I assume it is for later.
 
If later, then I think you have a bug in the code. The SDK client needs to pass an absolute UTC time to GenerateTestToken(). If you are passing the old time, then it is not going to work.
 
If that does not help, please send a Fiddler trace to us at amshelp@microsoft.com

Comment: hey i have used UTC time in GenerateTestToken()            
 string testToken = TokenRestrictionTemplateSerializer.GenerateTestToken(tokenTemplate, null, rawkey, DateTime.UtcNow.AddMinutes(2));  still i am facing the same issues , i do not understand where the bug is because it works fine almost 2 out of 3 times its just 1 time token does not work for decryption